# Laravel 5.4 - TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

Error:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:
```

Tokens:

```
Token: KtRuC4JIT5ANiUvHf4ppcm5gHn1w9hYXc7yYS2Yz
ST: LvQ2yi0QdLcTSlIY4SxuNYhGswNZGUnInRorxQkG
```

How am I displaying tokens?

```
echo 'Token: ' . $token;
echo 'ST: ' . $request->session()->token(); 
exit();
```

Have I added the _token input? 
Yes, this was working fine for some time while developing, but randomly broke during development.

Have I tried just `return true;` on top of the `tokensMatch` function?
Yes, that just redirects me to the login page without any messages, logs me in but instantly logs me out back to the login page.

Anyone who can help?

Comment: In your HTML form add following Line after form open `<form>`and before `</form>` `{!! csrf_field() !!}` It will add a CSRF Token field in your form and then it should work...

Comment: I have already said I have added the _token input.

Comment: are you using `csrf_token()` function???

Comment: Yes I am using that

Comment: Since you added `csrf_token()` check your browser cookie enabled.

Comment: Could you find a solution? I'm having similar issue